# Laravel 5 query builder, complicated join (condition AND (condition OR condition))

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, eloquent, laravel-query-builder

I need to reproduce the following query in Laravel's query builder:

```
select * from table LEFT JOIN table_b ON `condition` AND (`condition` OR `condition`)
```

I know you can do complicated `where` statements like this:

```
Model::where(function ($query) {
  return $query->where("field","value")->orWhere("field","value");
})->where("field","value")->get();
```

And I know you can do semi-complicated `on` statements like this:

```
->leftJoin('table', function ($join) {
  $join->on("field","=","field_b")
    ->on("field_a","=","field_c");
})
```

But I need to have `condition AND (condition OR condition)` INSIDE an `on` statement. Is this possible without doing `DB::raw()` or equivalent?

Comment: see here https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/queries `Advanced Join Clauses`

Comment: My specific case wasn't found in the documentation (which I've already read). I got an answer that works already though. Thanks for your time

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this:

```
->leftJoin('table', function ($join) {
    $join->on("field","=","field_b")
        ->on(function($join) {
            $join->on("field_a","=","field_c")
                ->orOn("field_d","=","field_e");
        });
})
```

Comment: Thanks. This actually isn't documented on https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/queries , (specifically for "on" statements anyways) but it works great.